# Exact behaviour of --mno-unaligned-access

Tags: c, assembly, arm, clang, eabi

I'll start with the question, and will follow it by an example.
The description of this flag in ARM Compiler armclang Reference Guide Version 6.4 ([link](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0774/e/Compiler-Command-line-Options/-munaligned-access---mno-unaligned-access)) says:

> If unaligned access is disabled, words in packed data structures are accessed one byte at a time.

As you can see in the following example, after the 1 byte access on line `1e0` there is (aligned) word access on line `1e2`. By the above description I would expect that the form of access on `1e0` would be used to the rest of the bytes of `M[1].A`. I would like to ask for an exact description of the behavior with this flag set: does it always as in this example? meaning that over aligned addresses it will be able to extract words even on packed structs?

Example: for this code,

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(1))) MyStruct{
    int A;
    short B;
    char C;
} MyStruct_t;
int main(void) {
    MyStruct_t M[2];
    int D, E;
    M[0].A = 0xffffffff;
    M[1].A = 0xeeeeeeee;
    D = M[0].A;
    E = M[1].A;
    D = E;
    return 0 ;
}
```

compiled with `--mno-unaligned-access` and like that (using MCUXpresso ide):

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -nostdlib -Xlinker -Map="m7_experiments.map" -Xlinker --cref -Xlinker --gc-sections -Xlinker -print-memory-usage -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -T "m7_experiments_Debug.ld" -o "m7_experiments.axf" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

I'm getting the following machine code:

```
000001b0 <main>:
 1b0:   b480            push    {r7}
 1b2:   b087            sub     sp, #28
 1b4:   af00            add     r7, sp, #0
 1b6:   f04f 33ff       mov.w   r3, #4294967295 ; 0xffffffff
 1ba:   603b            str     r3, [r7, #0]
 1bc:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1be:   f063 0311       orn     r3, r3, #17
 1c2:   71fb            strb    r3, [r7, #7]
 1c4:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1c6:   f063 0311       orn     r3, r3, #17
 1ca:   723b            strb    r3, [r7, #8]
 1cc:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1ce:   f063 0311       orn     r3, r3, #17
 1d2:   727b            strb    r3, [r7, #9]
 1d2:   727b            strb    r3, [r7, #9]
 1d4:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1d6:   f063 0311       orn     r3, r3, #17
 1da:   72bb            strb    r3, [r7, #10]
 1dc:   683b            ldr     r3, [r7, #0]
 1de:   617b            str     r3, [r7, #20]
 1e0:   79fb            ldrb    r3, [r7, #7]
 1e2:   68ba            ldr     r2, [r7, #8]
 1e4:   f022 427f       bic.w   r2, r2, #4278190080     ; 0xff000000
 1e8:   0212            lsls    r2, r2, #8
 1ea:   4313            orrs    r3, r2
 1ec:   613b            str     r3, [r7, #16]
 1ee:   693b            ldr     r3, [r7, #16]
 1f0:   617b            str     r3, [r7, #20]
 1f2:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1f4:   4618            mov     r0, r3
 1f6:   371c            adds    r7, #28
 1f8:   46bd            mov     sp, r7
 1fa:   f85d 7b04       ldr.w   r7, [sp], #4
 1fe:   4770            bx      lr
```

EDIT: with the complementary flag `munaligned-access` we receive what would be expected on this case:

```
000001b0 <main>:
 1b0:   b480            push    {r7}
 1b2:   b087            sub     sp, #28
 1b4:   af00            add     r7, sp, #0
 1b6:   f04f 33ff       mov.w   r3, #4294967295 ; 0xffffffff
 1ba:   603b            str     r3, [r7, #0]
 1bc:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1be:   f063 0311       orn     r3, r3, #17
 1c2:   71fb            strb    r3, [r7, #7]
 1c4:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1c6:   f063 0311       orn     r3, r3, #17
 1ca:   723b            strb    r3, [r7, #8]
 1cc:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1ce:   f063 0311       orn     r3, r3, #17
 1d2:   727b            strb    r3, [r7, #9]
 1d4:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1d6:   f063 0311       orn     r3, r3, #17
 1da:   72bb            strb    r3, [r7, #10]
 1dc:   683b            ldr     r3, [r7, #0]
 1de:   617b            str     r3, [r7, #20]
 1e0:   f8d7 3007       ldr.w   r3, [r7, #7]
 1e4:   613b            str     r3, [r7, #16]
 1e6:   693b            ldr     r3, [r7, #16]
 1e8:   617b            str     r3, [r7, #20]
 1ea:   2300            movs    r3, #0
 1ec:   4618            mov     r0, r3
 1ee:   371c            adds    r7, #28
 1f0:   46bd            mov     sp, r7
 1f2:   f85d 7b04       ldr.w   r7, [sp], #4
 1f6:   4770            bx      lr
```

Comment: This could be a compiler bug, but could you verify if you're passing `-mno-unaligned-access` correctly? (note that there's a single `-`, not two). Also, I think the first write of `0xffffffff` in `1ba` already violates your expectations (though it could be that the compiler is taking advantage of the already known stack alignment here).

Comment: @Hasturkun yea, I agree with you over the write, although I did not mention it. Also, yes, I verified it. I add to the main post how is it with allowing unaligned access (it's just do what would be expected on this case). Do you have any guess? I did not find a detailed reference for that flag

Comment: I can't reroduce this bahviour with godbolt.org.

Comment: @TomV does this https://godbolt.org/z/bGaa64Mj8 helps? I think it's the dame doesn't it? first byte accessed by byte, then it access to a word and shift it one byte left

Comment: After comparing both versions, it seems that with the flag or without it, it avoids write to unaligned address (so on both versions the write to the second struct was byte by byte) and it also seems that the flag doesn't prevent word access to aligned addresses, as it can be seen from my example. I would really like to verify the exact behavior though

Comment: It would be easy to believe that the docs oversimplify.  The behavior they describe is plausible, but what you now think you observe -- that byte-by-byte access is performed only to unaligned objects -- is both plausible and better.  It might be interesting to see what the compiler emits when the access is via a `MyStruct_t *` passed as a function argument from a different translation unit, so that there is no compile-time information about the alignment of the address.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/h7cWrzWbT is a much simpler example: a function that takes a pointer and returns a member.  Your unoptimized `main` is a big mess to wade through.  With `-mno-unaligned-access`, we get two separate `ldrb` because the whole struct's alignment isn't known, so it doesn't help that the `short B` member starts 4 bytes from the start of the struct.  (Why bother with "packed" when there'd be no padding between members without it, only 1 byte at the end to make the sizeof a multiple of alignof(int)?)

Comment: The (current) GCC definition for the flag says "Enables (or disables) reading and writing of 16- and 32- bit values from addresses that are not 16- or 32- bit aligned. [...]. If unaligned access is not enabled then words in packed data structures are accessed a byte at a time.". I'm taking this to mean `packed` implies unaligned, but doesn't force it on a struct that's already known to be aligned. `__builtin_assume_aligned ` (combined with `-O1` or higher) makes it behave similarly (with an alignment of 2 loading/storing the first element by halves, etc.) https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TMKMTxG3v

Comment: @Hasturkun: Yes, `packed` makes the `aligned(1)` attribute redundant; it's implied by `packed` even if we add another member to make the size be 8, a multiple of `alignof(MyStruct_t) = alignof(int)` without packed.  https://godbolt.org/z/qP3zr1TG8  So yes, alignment of an arbitrary pointed-to object is unknown, but stack alignment is known and compilers know where they put things on the stack.  And yes, it's about potentially-unaligned *access*, whether the compiler can prove that the access has known alignment, not the *minimum* required alignment for any object of that type.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour here is because even though the type is packed and potentially misaligned, the compiler knows that any instance of it on the stack must be aligned, and so aligned members of it can be accessed using word sized reads and writes.

If you access the packed struct through a pointer then the compiler doesn't know its alignment, and so the behaviour is very different.

I have not been able to reproduce this exact behaviour on godbolt because it doesn't have your version of armclang, but look at [this example compiled with gcc 11](https://godbolt.org/z/G5jqWcxoe):

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(1))) MyStruct{
    int A;
    short B;
    char C;
} MyStruct_t;

int main(void) {
    MyStruct_t M[2];
    int D, E;
    M[0].A = 0xffffffff;
    M[1].A = 0xeeeeeeee;
    D = M[0].A;
    E = M[1].A;
    D = E;
    return 0 ;
}

int fn(MyStruct_t *M) {
    int D, E;
    M[0].A = 0xffffffff;
    M[1].A = 0xeeeeeeee;
    D = M[0].A;
    E = M[1].A;
    D = E;
    return 0 ;
}
```

The same lines which use a `str` in the first function use four `strb` in the second.

Comment: You example is invalid as you have changed the CPU to M3 which **requires** aligned access. Do not make the example codes to meet your expectations. Use the  OPs settings

Comment: Yes, I've also said that I changed it from clang to gcc.  The godbolt example isn't really part of the answer, just a close equivalent.  By the way you might want to check the CM3 TRM: it is exactly the same as the CM4 and CM7 in this regard: it can do unaligned ldr/str, just not unaligned ldrd/strd or ldm/stm.

Comment: ldrd is not related here. Also FPU instructions

Answer (score 0):

Your struct is naturally aligned (and packed).  Try this instead.

```
{
    unsigned char C;
    unsigned short B;
    unsigned int A;
}
```

GCC appears to default to byte accesses, and clang (the one from llvm, I don't know what armclang is, nor did I have it nor try it) defaults to unaligned accesses.

I found that gnu always did stores a byte at a time but loads varied based on the command line option.  And clang the store and loads were based on the command line.

The quote from the link is already flawed because it only mentions words not halfwords nor double words (nor floats of any kind).  In any case you are correct, if the item is aligned the flag does not force it to be broken into byte accesses, the statement does not match (llvm) clang.   I do not know why one would want it to force byte accesses for aligned items as in your example.  It would make sense to have a flag to avoid unaligned accesses (as the name of the flag implies) and keep aligned ones.

The quote is also badly written as it implies the software might know if unaligned accesses are disabled.  There is no check in the code to see if the processor is set to block unaligned accesses.

You can contact ARM and see if you can get them to fix the web page.

> The flag causes packed structs to not generate unaligned accesses.

This is an example of something already significantly better.

> The flag causes access to packed structs to only generate aligned accesses.

This is another.

Comment: As discussed in comments, `__attribute__((packed))` (even without `aligned(1)`) sets `alignofMyStruct_t)` to 1, even if its size was a multiple of 4.  In this case it also sets `sizeof(MyStruct_t)` to 7 instead of 8, removing the trailing padding so it changes the alignment of `M[1].A`.

Comment: `-mno-unaligned-access` would also have an effect on `memcpy(&my_int, charptr, sizeof(foo))` and similar constructs for expressing an unaligned load other than packed structs.  The GCC / clang option's documentation should definitely not be changed to only talk about structs or packed structs.  Unless that's just one specific consequence they want to *mention*, not limit to.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html seems fairly good, although a bit outdated as you say with no mention of 64-bit accesses from the FPU or `ldrd`.

Comment: the text on the arm site mentions packed structs, I did not investigate beyond that.  It is poorly written either way.  The could have literally spent a few more seconds and written something better, maybe not correct, but better.